# Let's Encryptの更新を自動化したい

Tags: ssl

Let's Encryptの更新をしたくて更新作業はローカル環境でうまくいかなかったので、GUIで行えるサイトを利用して初めて行ったときと同じ作業をしました。
https://sslnow.ml/#
こちらです。

3か月ごとに、秘密鍵などのソースをレンサバで毎回設定するのは大変なのですが、自動更新はGUIでは行えないのでしょうか？

SSHが使えるレンサバならCUIではできるようですが、使えないレンサバは毎度初めての時と同じ作業をし続けないといけないのでしょうか？

更新時期もいつかわからないとある日使えなくなって急に行わないといけないので困ります。
期限間近の通知メールはちゃんと来るものですか？

Comment: 正しいメールアドレスで登録していれば通知メールは通常ちゃんと来ますよ。

Comment: 19日前には英語のメールが来るのでね。

Comment: ただ自動更新ができないと毎回3か月の一週間前くらいに0から作り直してサーバ側で秘密鍵などの張り付けもまた行わないといけないですよね。仕事が忙しい時に当たると困りませんか？

Comment: FTPでも自動化できるツールとかはありそうですね、あるいはネームサーバーがAPIで操れればDNS-01とか使った方がサーバー直接さわる必要なくて手っ取り早いわけではあるのですが……

Comment: ありがとうございます。
初めてやったときはCUIでかなりのコマンドをシェルで打ってローカルにファイルを作りサーバにアップロードしましたが、
これは自動化ではなくCUIでやっただけなので、やはりサーバ上でSSHで行えない限り自動化はできないのですね。

SSHが使えるレンサバに乗り換えれば可能という事ですね。

Comment: ん、SSHが必須とは言っていませんよ。ブラウザ上や手元のPCとFTP等で出来るようにそれらの一連のアクションは自動化が出来るはずです。もちろんそれで取得できた証明書をサーバーに設定するには自分でアップロードが必要かもしれませんが。

Comment: sshが使えないレンサバでもできるのですね

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's Encryptは「証明書を取得するための処理(CSRの発行とかドメインの確認とか)を自動で行う」というものです。取得が自動で出来れば更新も自動で出来る、という話なので、証明書の取得が手作業でしかおこなえないなら更新も手作業でやるしかありません。

なので、自動更新が必要なら、証明書を自動で取得できる環境を整えてください。サーバ上で直接作業が出来ないなら、別の環境で証明書を取得してコピーすることになります。(これはLet's Encryptでなくても同じです)

また、取得した証明書を実際に利用するための手順(しかるべき場所に証明書を配置するとか、サーバにそれを認識させるとか)の自動化というのはまた別の話です。これはLet's Encryptとは直接関係ありません。Let's Encryptの場合証明書の有効期限が短いので、これもセットで考えないといけない、というだけで、Let's Encryptと直接関係するわけではありません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
初めてやったときはCUIでかなりのコマンドをシェルで打ってローカルにファイルを作りサーバにアップロードしましたが、
これは自動化ではなくCUIでやっただけなので、やはりサーバ上でSSHで行えない限り自動化はできないのですね。

SSHが使えるレンサバに乗り換えれば可能という事ですね。